# How to select from list of divs - Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Angular 2.
Here are a list of divs :

```
<div class="list">
 <div value="A">A</div>
 <div value="B">B</div>
 <div value="C">C</div>
 <div value="D">D</div>
 <div value="E">E</div>
</div>
```

How do I select only one div from this (like a radio list) and then handle the selected value ?

Comment: is this list part of some component? use template reference and viewchild - `<div #c value="C">C</div>` and then in component '@ViewChild('c') divC`'

Comment: do you need to select it by clicking it like a radio button?

Comment: @crash Yes, Behaviour like a radio button. But modified like a list of buttons, Where only one div is selectable from that list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="list">
 <div value="A" [class.highlight]="selection=='A'" (click)="clickFunction('A')">A</div>
 <div value="B" [class.highlight]="selection=='B'"  (click)="clickFunction('B')">B</div>
 <div value="C" [class.highlight]="selection=='C'"  (click)="clickFunction('C')">C</div>
 <div value="D" [class.highlight]="selection=='D'"  (click)="clickFunction('D')">D</div>
 <div value="E" [class.highlight]="selection=='E'" (click)="clickFunction('E')">E</div>
</div>

selection = "A";
clickFunction(value){
console.log(value)
this.selection = value;

}
```

Comment: Right. But what about handling the selection? where only one div is highlighted at any point in time? Should I use some boolean and set/unset `highlight` classes dynamically?

Comment: Ya. You should use `highlight` class. See my updated answer

Comment: Can we write it like this? `<div *ngFor="let item of ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']" [class.highlight]="selection==item" (click)="clickFunction(item)">{{item}}</div>`

Comment: @yurzui, Sure, we can and should write like this.